# Execute a command before rsync --delete-after takes place

Tags: files, rsync, command, delete

What I want to do exactly is to sync the files , execute a command and wait for it to finish , then use the --delete-after option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to do that with one `rsync` call, but you could mimic this behaviour by running `rsync` without `--delete` (or `--delete-after`), then execute your command and run the same `rsync` command this time with the `--delete` option afterwards.

Example:

```
rsync -avh src/ dest && command && rsync -avh --delete src/ dest
```